# How does Laughlin argument for hierarchical fractional quantum Hall effect work?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect, anyons

For 1 level and 1 layer $1/q$ FQHE let's say $q=5$ we have the following argument for Laughlin gauge principle. It says that if we adiabatically increase the flux from $0$ to $q\phi_0$ of a corbino disk in $T$ amount of time, than $q$ states should move to the adjacent state, since the filling factor is $1/q$ it means that total of $1$ electron moved from inner circle to outer circle. 
thus $$I=e/T$$ and $$V=q\phi_0/T$$ so we have$$I/V=e/(q\phi_0)=\frac{1}{q}\frac{e^2}{h}$$ thus we prove the conductivity.

So let's make the same thing for $q=5/2$ now I think we can't follow the same reasoning. If $q=5/2$ than the minimum charge of a quasi-particle is $-e/5$. Keeping this in mind if we adiabatically increase the flux from $0$ to $5\phi_0$ of a corbino disk in $T$ amount of time again $5$ states should move to the adjacent state. The filling factor is $2/5$ so there is a $2/5$ charge for each state which means that the amount of charge goes from inside to outside is $5\times\frac{2}{5}=2$. So we continue as follows,

$$I=\frac{2e}{T}$$
$$V=5\phi_0/T$$
and

$$I/V=\frac{2}{5}\frac{e^2}{h}$$

which gives the correct conductivity.
I want to ask that whether my approach is correct or not?